# Installing Java on Windows 8

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm in a Java I class and I have a new-ish laptop with Windows 8 on it. I've installed Java and changed the environment variables, created a Path, etc. When I enter java or javac in the cmd, it comes back with information. But when I enter "java-version" (as I'm instructed to do in the class to test if Java is working) it says, "'java-version' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

I've even attempted a HelloWorld program in spite of this, and as you can imagine, I got the same message. I'm not even able to change the directory.

Is there some special way to install this on Windows 8 or what?

Comment: Did you type `java-version` or `java -version` (with a space)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to type `java -version` instead of `java-version`

Answer (score 1):

First of all ensure you have typed Java -version space between Java and -version

No there's not special way to install Java on windows 8 machine, Just ensure that you have added ..\Java\jdk_(version)\bin and ..\Java\jre\bin in environmental variables.

Steps to be followed :

1. Right click on my computer go to properties
2. Then go to Advanced
3. system properties then click on environment variables

and add both path in Path variable under System Variables add semicolon between two paths

**after all process don't forget to restart your PC**

Answer (score 0):

There is no special way to `install` java on `windows 8`. You can install java in normal way what you did in `windows 7` or `vista` or `windows xp` and configure. Then run  `java -version`, It will give your java version.